# Change keyboard laylout for Android on VMWare

Tags: keyboard, vmware

I have successfully installed Android 7.1 on my VMWare Workstation Player 15 but I want to change the keyboard layout to a german layout. Does anyone know which config file needs to be changed to achieve this? Is there a way to to this while the OS is running or does one have to do it over the console in a debug mode?

Best regards

Comment: What sort of Android system did you install? Android-x86 or some other emulator image?

Answer (score 0):

My host system has a german keyboard layout. When I changed the android keyboard layout to english the keyboard input of my guest system became german. I hope this helps someone.

Best regards

Comment: I am sorry but this answer does not make sense. I think you made a mistake.

Comment: I'm sorry for that inconvenient answer. I changed some words so I hope it makes more sense now. In other words : The keyboard input which was german on my host system but was translated into english keyboard inputs by either the VMWare Workstation Player or the OS itself changed to german input on the guest system aswell after adjusting the  guest system as explained in the answer.